# Is this considered a regular expression?

Tags: notation, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I need to design an NFA that recognizes the language $L$, with alphabet $\{a,b\}$, that accepts strings that:

- have length at least 4
- two letters before the final letter of the string there is always a $b$

For example the language accepts $abba$ but neither $aba$ nor $abbaba$.   I designed this:
[image]

If I wanted to provide a regular expression also I was wondering if I could write :
$(a|b)^*b(a|b)^2$
I have never seen an exponent as $2$ that's why I am concerned.

Comment: You can always write $(a|b)^*b(a|b)(a|b)$ if you are unsure.

Comment: @player3236's suggestion is the best. The RegEx support in most programming environments also includes $\{m\}$ shortcut syntax for specifying exactly $m$ occurrences. So, you would have: $(a|b)∗b(a|b)\{2\}$

Comment: @vvgiri ah i see.. i didnot know that , thank you people

Comment: Since mathematics is fairly big tent, this does fit into it. But still, I think you would have been much better off asking it in a computer science forum.

Comment: To clarify: the mathematic theory of regular expressions (defined from the letters using union, product and star) is definitely on topic on this site. Questions about RegEx as defined in programming languages are not on topic and should rather be addressed to cs.stackexchange.com  or to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting by $A$ the alphabet, your language is $A^*AbA^2$.
If $L$ is any language, $L^n$ is defined by induction as follows: $L^0 = \{1\}$
(where $1$ denotes the empty word, which is the identity of the free monoid $A^*$) and $L^{n+1} = L^nL$. Thus $L^2 = LL$.

You can remove state $1$ in your non-deterministic automaton.